# Parse Android disable Push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

How to disable push notifications in the new Parse Android SDK?

I have a preference in my app which is for disable notification. So when the user uncheck the preference I want to disable the notifications (shut down the push service) for the app. For example in the old SDK you just have to call PushService.setDefaultCallback(null) and the push service is stopped.

This is how I subscribe for push notifications on my Application class:

```
@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize the Parse SDK.
    Parse.initialize(this, BuildConfig.PARSE_APP_ID, BuildConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);

    // Register for Push Notifications ?
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean notificationsEnabled =
            sharedPref.getBoolean(SettingsFragment.PREF_KEY_ENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS, true);
    if(notificationsEnabled){
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Timber.d("successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Timber.e(e, "failed to subscribe for push");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On my preferences fragment this how I listen for preference change:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if(key.equals(PREF_KEY_ENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS)){
        boolean notificationsEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_ENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS, true);
        if(notificationsEnabled){
            ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Timber.d("successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                    } else {
                        Timber.e(e, "failed to subscribe for push");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Timber.d("successfully un-subscribed from the broadcast channel.");
                    } else {
                        Timber.e(e, "failed to un-subscribe for push");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PsyDuck I added the code example to the question above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling/disabling receivers doesn't help also. Strangely, after reenabling, the app can't receive pushes. The best way I've reached is:

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {...}

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Esperandro.getPreferences(Prefs.class, context).show_notifications()) { //your shared preferences
            super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it much easier to subscribe users to a "default" channel.  Then, if they turn push notifications off, you can just remove that from the list of channels.  It also makes it a little nicer when you trigger the push notifications to go to an actual channel, instead of just everyone.

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
List<String> channels = PushNotificationManger.getDefaultChannels();
installation.put("channels", channels);
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to Parse.com and open your application's setting page. Then open 'Push' tab and toggle the 'Client push enabled?'.[More Info Here.](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/Android)

See the image for clarity:

[image]

Comment: How can this not work? You want to disable push and this is how you do it.

Comment: So you say if I call ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("") to subscribe to the broadcast channel and then enable client push on the settings, and later call ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("") I'm supposed to not receive future notifications

Comment: @Gustavo you should edit the question then. I gave the answer according to what I read in your question.

Comment: So, you want to unsubscribe only one user but keep the Push active overall. So when you use `ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("Channel_name")` , what do you get in LogCat as a response?

Comment: Post some part of your code related to this. Let me see what you're doing and where you're doing it. The part where you're subscribing and the part where you're unsubscribing. + what exactly happens when you call `ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("Channel_name")`?